# Что именно происходит когда ЦС подписывает своим закрытом ключом сертификат

Tags: криптография, шифрование, windows-server

Что именно он делает, что шифрует своим закрытом ключом? сам сертификат? или же хэш этого сертификата?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 5280, параграф 4.1.1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.1.3):

> The signatureValue field contains a digital signature computed upon
> the ASN.1 DER encoded tbsCertificate.  The ASN.1 DER encoded
> tbsCertificate is used as the input to the signature function.  This
> signature value is encoded as a BIT STRING and included in the
> signature field.  The details of this process are specified for each
> of the algorithms listed in [RFC3279], [RFC4055], and [RFC4491].

Если по-русски, то:

- Сертификат - это структура данных на языке ASN.1

  - Для ASN.1 определены несколько правил кодирования. Одно из этих правил называется `DER`
- Для сертификата строится массив байтов в соответствии с правилами `DER`.
- Этот массив байтов скармливается алгоритму подписи.

  - Что именно делает с этими байтами алгоритм - зависит от алгоритма.
- Результат работы алгоритма и есть цифровая подпись сертификата

Алгоритмов придумано великое множество, но все, что я видел в реальной жизни, устроены одинаково: сначала вычисляется хэш байтовой строки, затем этот хэш подписывается или шифруется приватным ключом удостоверяющего центра.

Примеры: sha-1WithRSAEncryption, ecdsa-with-SHA1, GostR3411-94-with-GostR3410-2001 и т.д.